# Can't connect to a ssh server which run in the WSL

Tags: windows-10, openssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can start a openssh-server successfully. But can not connect to it.

Windows Version: Windows 10 pro 1703

OS Version: 15063.483

This is how i start the openssh-server:

1. Modify the sshd config

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

   - uncomment `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0`
   - set `UsePrivilegeSeparation no`
   - set `PasswordAuthentication yes`
2. start the openssh-server: `sudo service ssh start`
3. check the sshd status: `sudo service ssh status`, and return `* sshd is running`

I can see the `sshd` process in windows task manager, But I can't find the 22 port if i run `netstat -an` in cmd.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I don't know how to solve this question exactly. But I tried these steps when I met the same.

- Add the ssh port(default 22) into both In-bound and Out-bound rules
- try to use RSA key to login instead of the traditional password method
- try to `sudo apt-get remove openssh-server` and re-install it

And then it can be connected at last. So I don't know what is the Key step to solve this question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The ssh port is already in both rules. I try to re-install it, but still not work. I found a warning `invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel` after installing

Comment: try to change port 22 to another port which is not using? On my computer I have change it into 2222 because the 22 port has been used in port forward rules which connected to my Linux VM in Hyper-V.  edit: when you want to restart the ssh server, use `sudo service ssh --full-restart`

Comment: It's not work for me :(   Thanks for your reply.